# Powerbuilder query window is slow with ASE 16

Tags: powerbuilder, sap-ase

I am using PB 11.5 and 12.5 and ASE 16. When I do any query in the PB interactive SQL interface the query takes about 15 seconds before it starts to return data. When I do the same query in the Windows command prompt using ISQL, the response is immediate with no wait time.
What would PB be doing that takes so long to start the query?

Answer (score 0):

ISQL works directly with they Sybase Client you have installed, while PowerBuilder works through its own PB Native Database driver for access into the Sybase client and has additional capabilities. So, scrutinize the settings you have in your PowerBuilder Database Profile:

1. From the Database Painter in PB 11.5, right click on your specific connection to the ASE16 database and choose "Properties".
2. Review the settings on each of the tabs, some of these can cause problems when not used correctly (or can solve problems when used correctly).
3. For help here at stackoverflow, copy the text in the "Preview" tab and paste it here (obscuring private specifics). Of particular importance will be SQLCA.DBParm=
4. As a quickie suggestion, you can try choosing different "Release" versions on the Connection tab.

You have not shared much information, for now that is all I can suggest. It would be nice to know, for example, what Sybase client you have installed.